# Delete an element inside a JSON array by value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Part of my json Array

```
var videos = $j.parseJSON('
  [
    { "privacy":"public",
      "id":"1169341693" },

    { "privacy":"private",
      "id":"803641223" },

    { "privacy":"public",
      "id":"1300612600" }, ......
```

When I console.log the element I'm getting

```
   [Object, Object, Object, …]
       0: Object
           privacy: "public"
           id: "1169341693"
       1: Object
           privacy: "private"
           id: "803641223"
       2: Object
           privacy: "public"
           id: "1300612600"
```

I also have a unique id I want to search for

```
var uniqueId = 803641223;
```

I want to find, in my videos array, the right id, and delete that whole array element. So In that case, I want my final videos array to contain only 2 object, instead of 3 :

```
 var videos = $j.parseJSON('
  [
    { "privacy":"public",
      "id":"1169341693" },

    { "privacy":"public",
      "id":"1300612600" }, ......
```

My problem is how to get in the array to do my splice. I prefer to do it with jQuery

Any help please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) :

```
videos = $.grep(videos, function(e) { return e.id!='803641223' });
```

In vanilla JavaScript you could have used the similar [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function but it's not supported by IE8.

Please note that `videos` is a JavaScript array, it's not a JSON array, even if it was made by parsing a JSON string.

Comment: @Lelly Note that this creates a new array with the elements acceptable (don't have the specific `id` property). `splice` modifies the array in place. It depends on which you want.

Comment: oh, in that special case I need a splice to modify the original array. Can I use your solution with splice ?

Comment: @Lelly So dystroy's solution **re-assigns** the value of `videos`, to the "filtered" list. Technically, it's accomplishing the same as `splice`, just doing a little extra work. If you want to keep the original array in `videos` but have the filtered array in a new variable, you could use: `var videos = [ blah blah blah ]; var filteredVideos = $.grep(videos, function(e) { return e.id!='803641223' });` - note how `videos` will still contain the original array, and `filteredVideos` will contain the filtered array (based on `uniqueId`). So you'd use `filteredArray` from there on.

Comment: @Lelly If you want to change the original array, use Ian's solution, it's OK. But check you prefer that : most often what you really want is a new array. – dystroy 2 mins ago edit

Comment: @dystroy If you agree/want to, you could include/explain that your example overwrites `videos` with the filtered array, technically doing the same thing as splicing. If you stored the result of the `$.grep` in another variable, you'd still have the original `videos` array and a new filtered array. So the example in my comment was using `var videos = [ blah blah blah ]; var filteredVideos = $.grep(videos, function(e) { return e.id!='803641223' });` - where that should satisfy keeping the original.

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure there is still something unclear for Lelly, especially after your comments.

Answer (score 4):

A non-jQuery solution that modifies the array in place:

```
var uniqueId = 803641223;
var videos = [
    { "privacy":"public",
      "id":"1169341693" },

    { "privacy":"private",
      "id":"803641223" },

    { "privacy":"public",
      "id":"1300612600" }
];

function cleaner(arr, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        var cur = videos[i];
        if (cur.id == uniqueId) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

cleaner(videos, uniqueId);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4JAww/1/

Note that this modifies the original array in place, such that the original `videos` array will have the items you want, and the one that matched the `uniqueId` will be gone (forever). So it depends on whether you want to be able to access the original array ever again, or are okay with modifying it.

It just loops through the elements of the array, compares the item's `id` property to the `uniqueId` value, and `splice`s if they match. I use `break;` immediately after the `splice` because you seem to imply that the `uniqueId` can/should only appear once in the array since it's...unique.

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can remove element with javascript splice function...

```
videos.items.splice(1, 3); // Removes three items starting with the 2nd,
```

Answer (score 0):

It worker for me.

```
  arrList = $.grep(arrList, function (e) { 

        if(e.add_task == addTask && e.worker_id == worker_id) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It returns an array without that object.

Hope it helps.