# Delete a record from json array

Tags: javascript

I Have an json array in the following format:

```
Object {field: "l0", headerText: "0-22", width: 120}
Object {field: "l1", headerText: "23-43", width: 120}
Object {field: "l2", headerText: "44-55", width: 120}
```

I want to delete a record on the basis of headerText value

i.e. I have value 0-22 and on the basis of this I have to delete this record. Is it possible?

Comment: Are these objects wrapped in an array ?

Comment: yes these are wrapped

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15367759

Comment: You can use the array's filter function to get the object/index and then remove it from array using `Array.splice()`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your objects are wrapped in an array, like this:

```
var arr = [
    {field: "l0", headerText: "0-22", width: 120},
    {field: "l1", headerText: "23-43", width: 120},
    {field: "l2", headerText: "44-55", width: 120}
];
```

You can do something like this:

```
var result = arr.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.headerText !== "0-22"; // Or whatever value you want to use
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.removeVal = function(name, value){
var array = $.map(this, function(v,i){
  return v[name] === value ? null : v;
});
this.length = 0; 
this.push.apply(this, array); //push all elements except the one we want to delete
}

var myArr = {};

myArray = [
{field: "l0", headerText: "0-22", width: 120},
{field: "l1", headerText: "0-11", width: 120},
{field: "l2", headerText: "0-33", width: 120}
];

myArray.removeVal('headerText', '0-11');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76u2eznq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i<jsonArray.length; i++){
    if(jsonArray[i]. headerText == "0-22"){
       jsonArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be a better answer if you describe your code there!

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://jsbin.com/niyegazare/1/edit?js,console,output).

```
var objects = [
  {field: 'l0', headerText: '0-22', width: 120},
  {field: 'l1', headerText: '23-43', width: 120},
  {field: 'l2', headerText: '44-55', width: 120}
];

function filterObjects(element, index) {
  if (element.headerText === '0-22') {
    objects.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

objects.forEach(filterObjects);

console.log(objects);
```